# Fitted equation with Predict

Tags: fitting, machine-learning

Is there a way to know the fitted curved from the function `Predict` when choosing the linear regression method.

I am using this data:

```
SeedRandom[144]
x = 2*RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];
y = 2 + 2*x + RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];
```

I am asking beacuse I use `LinearFitModel` in order to get the  equation of the best fit.

Comment: If the error term is a uniform distribution (rather than something more closely related to a normal distribution), then while the parameter estimates are probably unbiased, you won't be able to justify the use of any of the measures of precision (95% confidence bands, standard errors of parameters, etc.).  A fit is more than just the estimation of the parameters:  it also includes checking assumptions about the error structure.  This is why Machine Learning is many times thought of as "Statistics without the worry of checking on assumptions."

Comment: So, Predict performs worst than LinearModelFit?

Comment: No.  `Predict` performs identical to `LinearModelFit` when it comes to the estimates of the coefficients.  But when you start out with a uniform distribution for the error, `LinearModelFit` does not give appropriate estimates of precision and `Predict` doesn't give estimates of precision at all.  Maybe you were just using `RandomReal` to get an example dataset as opposed to mimicking the kind of data you actually have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p = Predict[x -> y, Method -> "LinearRegression"]
```

In versions 12.+, you can use the functions [`Information`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html) or [`PredictorInformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PredictorInformation.html):

```
Information[p, "Function"]
```

> ```
> 2.32989 + 2.1804 #1 &
> ```

```
PredictorInformation[p, "Function"]
```

> ```
> 2.32989 + 2.1804 #1 &
> ```

In version 11.0, you can use [`PredictorInformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PredictorInformation.html)

```
PredictorInformation[p, "Function"]
```

> ```
>   2.54578 + 1.9879 #1 &
> ```

Comment: In the documentation page says that it has been discontinued. Can it be done with only Information?

Comment: @LasDes, please see the update.